# How to hold a list mutable values in Haskell?

Tags: arrays, haskell, immutability

I would like to have an array, say:

`myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

and be able to run a function that changes a value in the list to another value. I would like to be able to run this function several times with `myArray` updating to the new set of numbers after each run.

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> f 1 5 myAarray 
>>> myArray
[1,2,3,4,1,6,7,8,9]
>>> f 3 8 myArray
>>> myArray
[1,2,3,4,1,6,7,3,9]
```

How do I create a holder for my values that can have changing values.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have mutable values in Haskell. Maybe you want to look into Monads?

Comment: Mutable values are this way -----> [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B)

Comment: @n.m. thanks and congrats on the most unhelpful comment I have come across yet!

Comment: You are welcome. Answers are supposed to be helpful, comments can bee jokes and whatnot. Are you a Haskell beginner? Your question doesn't have an answer that is both helpful and beginner-friendly. Well if you think "don't do it" is a helpful answer, then here you go.

Comment: @n.m. yes I am a Haskell beginner (very much so). Ok, I apologise for being sensitive. Perhaps the question was asked incorrectly. I was looking for a solution to a problem that is rather trivial in other languages... and hoping for help on how to get around the restrictions/rules of Haskell. Maybe help on a different way of thinking...

Comment: Storing mutable values is not by itself a problem that needs to be solved, it is a tool to solve other, real-world problems. Haskell is a powerful tool to solve real-world problems, built upon mostly immutable values. Immutability is essential for it to work. Haskell can have mutability too (IORef, State monad), but it's an advanced topic and it is very much advised to learn the basics before trying to deal with mutability.

Comment: If you are trying to learn Haskell, I would strongly suggest against trying to adapt knowledge from other languages to it. This path is likely to lead to very unidiomatic, hard-to-write code which can easily give you the impression that the language is cumbersome to use. This is not Haskell-specific: moving from any language X to another Y trying to shoehorn idioms from X into Y is very tempting, but rarely the right way.

Comment: @chi OTOH, there are still solutions that are expressed with a stateful context in a way that much more clearer and readable. Haskell is flexible enough to allow you provide a very scoped, narrow state solution which is much cleaner than what's provided by a lot of imperative languages anyway. I don't think avoiding representing, say, a chess board as a program state just for the sake of it is always worth it. It's exactly what you're trying to avoid, namely picking the solution before the problem. In principle, functions ending in `a -> a` are isomorphic to `State a *` anyway.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Agreed: for some tasks, mutability is really the best solution. I am just concerned that learning how to express that in the beginning will lead to bad Haskell code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Haskell values are immutable. You can't change a value that's bound to a name (you can *shadow* them in GHCi, but that's a slightly different thing).

If you want to achieve true<sup>1</sup> mutability, you need an immutable *reference* to mutable data. To use those, typically you'd want to be in a monadic context.

Here's an example using a rather low-level reference type called `IORef`:

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad

f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f = map (+1)

main = do
    a <- newIORef [1,2,3,4,5]
    readIORef a >>= print
    readIORef a >>= (return . f) >>= writeIORef a
    readIORef a >>= print
```

Note that the value of `a` doesn't change; it still points to the same "value location". What changes is the actual value that's being pointed to.

---

That being said, this requires using the `IO` monad which is generally frowned upon. Depending on your needs, a fully pure solution like `State` might work better.

```
-- assume previous f
g :: State [Int] ()
g = modify f
```

Now you only need to start with some state, and the state monad will chain the modifications for you, like so:

```
main = print $ execState (g >> g >> g) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is essentially equivalent to simple composition:

```
f . f . f $ [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Which, last but not least, could be your default go-to solution in Haskell.

---

P.S. I'm using a simpler `f` in my examples, but there's no reason you couldn't do:

```
(f 1 5) . (f 3 8) $ myArray
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This is somewhat ambiguous, but for the sake of simplicity I'd expand this to "the one that could be backed by direct memory operations".

Comment: thanks.  This is helpful. The idea was to have a list that will track what set a certain item in an array belongs to. The `f x y` puts the item at y in the same set as x etc. So, am I correct in believing that the only pure way of doing it is to somehow chain my functions either directly or through `State`?

Comment: @matthias Pretty much yes. State is typically satisfactory though - there's a strict variant of it available, as well as the `StateT`  transformer. Other methods either use `IO` directly or via some safer wrapper (`ST` and `STM` would be notable examples of such).

Comment: I don't think you can change bindings in GHCi either; if I'm not very much mistaken, you can only shadow them.